# can't use onmousemove on 'range button' on mobile phone, anything to replace it with the same function?

Tags: javascript, android, css

I'am using 'onmousemove=incfont()' to connect button to javascript below:

```
<html>
    <div class="wrapper-fontsize">
        <div class="fontChanger">
        <span></span>
        <span>
          8 &nbsp;
          <input type="range" onmousemove="incfont();" id="fontsize" min="8" max="36" value="16" style="width: 80%;" /> 
          &nbsp; 36
        </span>
        <label style="display: block !important;">
          Font Size : 
          <span id="size">16</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</html>

<script>
// ====== Font Resizer ======
    var size;
    var save = localStorage.getItem('fontChange', size);

    if (localStorage.getItem('fontChange')) {
      var x = document.getElementById('novel-content');
      x.style.fontSize = save + "px";
      document.getElementById('size').innerHTML = save;
      document.getElementById('fontsize').value = save;
    } 

    function incfont() {
      var t = document.getElementById('fontsize').value;
      var x = document.getElementById('novel-content');
      x.style.fontSize = t + "px";
      size = t;
      document.getElementById('size').innerHTML = size;
      localStorage.setItem('fontChange', size);
    }

// ====== Open-Close The Tool ======

    const closeFontChange = document.querySelector(".wrapper-fontsize");

    function openFontChanger() {
      closeFontChange.classList.add("active");
    }

    closeFontChange.addEventListener("click", function () {
      closeFontChange.classList.remove("active");
    });
</script>
```

Then:

1. I tried it on desktop and the text can change its font size correctly when drag.
2. Then I tried it on chrome on the mobile phone. Then there is a bug, whatever I did with the range button, the font size didn't want to change (follow the javascript)
3. At first I think it's all because of the version of my phone (6.0 marshmallow) so I use the chrome 'inspect element' to run the web through device sight (ctrl + shift + M ). Then number 2 problem happen on it.
4. The problem isn't about the local storage. Fortunately, the local storage work well both on the desktop or mobile. The local storage can save the variable number and start the function with it.

So far, I hypothesize that mobile phones cannot accept "onmausemove" function. So if it's true, is there anything to replace it with the same function?

Comment: The question is too many. Seems all questions are clear to answer but I hope you can ask one question for a question.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is simple, but maybe i've to change its structure. Since i can't use 'onmausemove', just use another way, like onclick, but the same function. Here:

```js
let ids = ["#content"];

// ====== Font Change ======

function changeFontSize(type) {
ids.forEach(id => {
    let el = document.querySelector(id);
    let fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
    fontSize = parseFloat(fontSize);
    if(type === "increase" & fontSize < 24){
        el.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 2) + "px";
    }else if (type === "decrease" & fontSize > 12){
        el.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 2) + "px";
    }
    var rest = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
    var size = rest.replace('px', '');
document.getElementById('size').innerHTML = size;
})
}
```

```css
body {
            background: #d8d8d8;
        }

        .wrapper {
            background: #fff;
            padding: 4px 16px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }

        .wrapper p, .wrapper h1 {
            color: #000;
            text-align: justify;
            line-height: 2;
            font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0.8em;
        }

        .wrapper p {
            font-size: inherit;
        }

        .wrapper h1 {
            font-size: 28px;
        }

        button {
            background: transparent;
            padding: 4px 20px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: none;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            transition: all .3s ease;
            user-select: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        button:hover {
            background: #1f1d34;
            color: #fff;
        }
```

```html
<div class="post-wrapper" style="filter: brightness(100%);">
    <div class="wrapper" id="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-fontsize">
    <div class="fontChanger">
        <h4>Font Size</h4>
        <button onclick="changeFontSize('decrease')">A-</button>
            <span id="size">16</span>
        <button onclick="changeFontSize('increase')">A+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```